# Execute first existing Docker credential helper and capture results

Tags: bash, docker

I'm working on some development tooling and need to query Docker's [credential helpers](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers). This tooling could run on any developers machine with the only given (at the moment) that they run on macOS.

Some developers prefer Docker Desktop so use the `desktop` credential helper. Others are using Colima with the `osxkeychain` helper.

The args and return values are always the same for each helper, it's just the specific executable that differs.

Currently I have a messy `if..elif..else` block with a lot of repeated code.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

getCreds() {
  if command -v docker-credential-desktop > /dev/null; then
    set +e
    creds=$(echo my.docker.registry | docker-credential-desktop get)
    set -e
  elif command -v docker-credential-osxkeychain > /dev/null; then
    set +e
    creds=$(echo my.docker.registry | docker-credential-osxkeychain get)
    set -e
  # elif... any other credential helpers
  else
    echo "No valid Docker Credential Helpers found"
    exit 1
  fi

  # parse JSON, etc...
}
```

I'm basically after some sort of *coalesce* function for a list of executables but so far I'm not finding anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what's expected :

```
getCreds() {
    local list_commands=(docker-credential-desktop docker-credential-osxkeychain)
    local cmd found_one=0
    for cmd in "${list_commands[@]}"; do
        if command -v $cmd &> /dev/null; then
            found_one=1
            set +e
            creds=$(echo my.docker.registry | $cmd get)
            set -e
            break
        fi
    done
    if test $found_one = 0; then
        echo "No valid Docker Credential Helpers found"
        exit 1
    fi
    # parse JSON, etc...
}
```